# Blank spaces when using fstream to write a

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

Using fstream to write a string in a file is putting a blank space between every letter, the string i am writing comes from a function that converts binary code into a ascii:

```
void almacenar(string texto)
{    
    string temp;   
    string test = "hola";   
    string compreso =""; 

    remove("compreso.daar");

    int textosize=texto.size();   
    int i = 0;

    while (i<textosize){   
        while(temp.size()!=8){   
            temp=temp+texto[i];  
            i++;   
            if (i>=textosize) {   
                break;
            }
        }    
        compreso=compreso+bitoascii(temp);   
        temp.clear();   
    }     
    Escribir(test,"compreso.daar");
}

int Escribir(string i,const char* archivo)
{   
    fstream outputFile;   
    outputFile.open(archivo, fstream::app);       
    outputFile<<i;   
    outputFile.close();   
    return 0;   
}     

string bitoascii(std::string data)
{  
   std::stringstream sstream(data);  
    std::string output;  
    while(sstream.good())  
    {
        std::bitset<8> bits;  
        sstream >> bits;  
        char c = char(bits.to_ulong());  
        output += c;  
    }
   return output;
}
```

The file sould have "Ø" have "Ø " or "ØØ" is "Ø Ø" if i print via console the string that contains Ø it has no spaces

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: BTW, you should declare `textosize` as `const int` since it doesn't change after assignment.  Similarly for other variables.

Comment: Is `Ø` an ASCII character? What's its [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)? How do you know there are spaces?

Comment: Because when it writes the txt file, there are blank space between every letter, but if i print it via console it has no space

Comment: Ø is just an example, this is for a huffman compressor

Comment: if i directly write something with the writing function (Escribir) it works how it should work

Answer (score 0):

In the function `bitoascii()`, after transferring data from `sstream` to `bits` you are not checking if the transfer succeeded and instead of having converted data, the value of `bits` is 0x00 and the value is recorded in the file, but the character `'\0'` is not printable.

> Just add a `sstream.good()` to know if `bits` has been correctly
>   written before adding the characters in the output string.

The function `bitascii()` should be:

```
string bitoascii(std::string data)
{  
   std::stringstream sstream(data);  
    std::string output;  
    while(sstream.good())  
    {
        std::bitset<8> bits;  
        sstream >> bits;
        // check is the transfer failed then exit from while
        if (!sstream.good()) break;  
        char c = char(bits.to_ulong());  
        output += c;  
    }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Humm, thank you too, I haven't played with `bitset` before. So, helping and playing are the best.